# Is there a way to see previous (government) emergency notifications?

Tags: iphone, notifications

At 3pm today (BST) the British government executed a test of their emergency alert system and caused an alarm on everyone's phone (the whole country).

Pretty cool actually.

The message appeared on everyone's phone with an alarm but I don't know what mechanism it used. It's not a regular text message.

On an iPhone, how can I see the text of that message if I already dismissed the alert?

---

These alerts appear to be related to the options at the bottom of "notifications" settings for "emergency alerts" and "severe alerts".

Noted here https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-65177316

Comment: It’s not a text (SMS) message so it doesn’t come through Messages App.  Check your Notifications

Comment: It doesn't seem to be anywhere i can find. We're on BST, btw, not GMT [not that it really matters for this]

Comment: It was on https://www.gov.uk/alerts/current-alerts for about 15 minutes, it's already dropped to Past Alerts.

Comment: In general no, Apple messages is not designed to keep around and let you inspect past app notifications - they come and they go and what is logged is obfuscated or not even kept around in the past.

Comment: @bmike - kind of irritating - you hear the sound, lift up the phone to see the alert [even though we were expecting it, no-one here had ever seen one before] then unlock the phone for more info… which deletes the alert entirely. :\

Comment: I can imagine the discussions at HQ on changing the design / making this work given how they implemented it on top of the APNS. You are very very correct that missing the alert is horribly failing at the point of the exercise @Tetsujin

Comment: Actually, not everyone got the alert. About 2/3 of the people where I was got it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have not dismissed it completely it yet, you can see the message again from the notifications history. Swipe down from the top center of the display to view your notifications history - it should appear in there.

Depending on your location, the authorities usually have a web site where you can view current and past emergency alerts. For the UK, that would be the [UK Emergency Alert System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Emergency_Alert_System) at this site:

https://www.gov.uk/alerts/current-alerts

Note that emergency alerts are not ordinary text messages. They do not appear in the Messages app as they are not ordinary SMS text messages, MMS messages nor are they Flash SMS messages.

Instead Emergency Alerts has dedicated support in the communications protocol between your phone and the carrier. This is done so that emergency alerts have priority over data and text messages in case the network is congested.

It is also done this way so that the authorities do not need to send targeted messages to each phone number - instead the message is sent using a method known [Cell Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) where every phone in a specific cell (area) receives the same, special SMS message. Your phone number is not used to send the message.

The UK is relatively late to having this type of emergency alert system. It is already in place in many countries in the world - including several countries in the EU and the USA - and has been in use for many years (as far as I remember, the first implementations where in 2012).

Comment: Ah, right. You can only do that with the phone unlocked. Didn't know that bit existed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

## Region Dependent

The implementation details depends on the geographic region involved. Unfortunately, this is not a standardised system. See [Public Warning Implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast#Public_warning_implementations) on Wikipedia.

### Legacy Approach – Flash SMS

If the message was delivered as a flash SMS, then the contents were not stored on your iPhone.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Flash_SMS for an overview of the mechanism that could be used across a broad range of mobile devices:

> A Flash SMS is a type of SMS that appears directly on the main screen without user interaction and is not automatically stored in the inbox. **It can be useful in emergencies**, such as a fire alarm or cases of confidentiality, as in delivering one-time passwords.

Comment: But it wasn't delivered as a flash SMS, so this answer doesn't apply here.

Comment: I have detailed it in my answer just now!

Comment: @GrahimMiln You write that the details depends on the geographic region and that it is not a standardised system - and you point to  a list of different system. In actuality, all of those systems on the list use the same standardized protocol - namely the Cell Broadcast feature in LTE - and thus they behave in the same manner and use the same implementation on the iPhone itself.

Comment: Not just on the iPhone - it's the same protocol used for Android. And yes, ofcourse older iPhones running iOS versions before this functionality was standardised and implemented do not support Emergency Alerts. The same goes for Android. That's how it is with software.

Comment: You can find some of the relevant technical documentation and specifications on the 3GPP.org website. The reference I use is a paid product that I unfortunately cannot just send you a copy of. You'll want to look at the specification for BMC (take a look at 25.324 and 25.301 as a start). In particular this feature is implemented with a BMC message with ID number 3 - the message containing identifiers for a geographical scope, a message code, update number, the coding scheme and actual payload data (i.e. the message).